# Wrong API on file-upload using Cypress.io for E2E testing

Tags: node.js, cypress, ui-automation, e2e-testing, browser-automation

I am testing a portal with Cypress.io, which has a file upload functionality.

But my file always failed to upload because the API call is going wrong.

Correct API Call:
**

> POST 200 /etl/v1.0.0/datauploaderetl/spaces/etl_jyddc0tx/data-files

**

But when uploading through Cypress, the following is the URL:
**

> POST 404 /etl/v1.0.0/datauploaderetl/data-files

**
As you can clearly see, the API is incorrect. I added the wait here, still, it doesn't work.
Following is the piece of code:

```
cy.fixture(fileName1).then(fileContent => {
        cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile({
            fileContent: fileContent.toString(),
            fileName: fileName1,
            mimeType: fileType
        })
    });
    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get(":nth-child(98) > .modal > .modal-lg > .modal-content > .modal-body")
        .should('contain.text', 'Status: completed')
    );
```

[image: This is how the modal looks like after uploading a file]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Command.js, add below code:

```
let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

Cypress.Commands.add("saveLocalStorage", () => {
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
        LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
    });
});

Cypress.Commands.add("restoreLocalStorage", () => {
    Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
        localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
    });
});
```

Then at the test case file, add below beforeEach and afterEach block respectively:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        cy.saveLocalStorage();
    })
```

This will solve the issue where Cypress clears the "local storage" at the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation this is the way to upload file :

```
cy.fixture('filepath').as('filetoupload')
cy.get('input[type=file]').then(function($input) {
  // convert the logo base64 string to a blob
  const blob = Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.filetoupload, fileType)
  $input.fileupload('add', { files: blob })
})
```

or

cy.fixture('filepath').as('filetoupload')

```
cy.get('input[type=file]').then(function(el) {
  // convert the logo base64 string to a blob
  const blob = Cypress.Blob.base64StringToBlob(this.filetoupload,fileType )

  const file = new File([blob], '<path>', { type: fileType })
  const list = new DataTransfer()

  list.items.add(file)
  const myFileList = list.files

  el[0].files = myFileList
  el[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }))
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/blob.html#Image-Fixture

Comment: Thank's for the answer. However, there was no problem with the file upload. The problem was that the cypress clears the browser's local storage before running. Hence all the permissions were lost during execution. The workaround is to add a code at beforeEach() and afterEach() to restoreLocalStorage and saveLocalStorage respectively.

Comment: You can  add that answer

Comment: The answer to my above issue is below:

Comment: I meant add it as a separate answer it would be help ful for others you can accept your own answer after a day

Comment: yes i upvoted good that you where able to solve it